# Provisioned throughput collection should have a partition key error when creating partitionless collection

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I created a document db database with RU shared at DB level rather than at container level. Is it possible to create a collection without partition under the same DB? When I try to do the same with the code below I get an error

> Provisioned throughput collection should have a partition key

```
private async Task CreatePartitionLessCollection()
{
    try
    {
        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
        DocumentCollection myCollection = new DocumentCollection();
        myCollection.Id = "MyCollection";
        await documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("MyDB"), myCollection, new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 400 });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce your issue on my side,it indicates that we can't create provisioned throughput collection without partition key. Because the throughput setting at the db level will be shared across all the inside 
collections :

[image]

Please see this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sharing-provisioned-throughput-across-multiple-containers-in-azure-cosmosdb/) to know the choice about setting db level or container level throughput.If you want to create a few partitioned collections and a few non-partitioned collections,you could try to set it at collection level.

Some key statements:

> Provisioning throughput for individual containers will guarantee the
>   reservation of throughput for that specific Cosmos DB container (i.e.,
>   a table or a collection or a graph) backed by the throughput SLA for
>   that container. This allows you to have a fine-grained control over
>   the throughput you want for a container at any given point in time. On
>   the other hand, provisioning throughput on a Cosmos DB database,
>   allows you to share the throughput among all the containers that
>   belong to that database. This allows you to pool the provisioned
>   throughput across a set of containers within a Cosmos DB database.

Comment: I agree that the throughput is what being shared. In my case i want a non partitioned collection. May be my understanding is wrong about partition and throughput sharing.

Comment: @ArjunMenon If you want to set non-partitioned collection,why not set throughput at collection level,rather than db level?

Comment: the system is an existing one and for bulk update we wrote SP in docDB which has some issue with partitioned collection.